# Adding @Conditional to an existing spring annotation in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have an application which uses an existing spring annotation (`@EnableResourceServer`). I want this particular annotation to be enabled only when a particular property value is not false.
To do this, I created a meta-annotation and applied `@ConditionalOnProperty` on that :

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "custom.resource", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@EnableResourceServer
public @interface EnableCustomResourceSecurity {
}
```

In my application I'm now using `@EnableCustomResourceSecurity` like :

```
@EnableCustomResourceSecurity
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and it all works fine if the property is missing or true but when I change the property to `custom.resource.enabled=false` I get the following exception :

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
```

I tried putting this annotation in a couple of other places and noticed that when the conditional expression fails for this annotation, any annotation after this also stops getting processed.

What would be the correct way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your annotation `@EnableCustomResourceSecurity` has the meta annotation `@ConditionalOnProperty`. While it may *seem* as if it enables/disables the `@EnableResourceServer` annotation, it *actually* enables/disables your `MyApplication` bean as a whole. It is as if you would write:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ConditionalOnProperty(...)
@EnableResourceServer
public class MyApplication {
```

To avoid this, simply create an empty `SomeConfiguration` class and annotate it with your custom annotation:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCustomResourceSecurity
public class SomeConfiguration {}
```

Instead of adding it to your `MyApplication` class.

Comment: Thanks! Adding an empty configuration and annotating it works perfectly,
Btw, is there any way I can avoid this extra empty config and control the annotation based on my property directly? Like how the eureka client has a ```@EnableEurekaClient ``` annotation but I can disable the client by ```eureka.client.enabled=false```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, you don't even need a custom annotation but just an empty configuration as mentioned by Michiel. This configuration, in turn, will also import the `@EnableResourceServer` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "custom.resource", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class ResourceServerConfig {
    public ResourceServerConfig() {
        System.out.println("initializing ResourceServerConfig ...");
    }
}
```

If you want to control based on annotation, you can import the same configuration in the custom annotation as below:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(ResourceServerConfig.class)
public @interface EnableCustomResourceSecurity {
}
```